# Passenger for RoR and LAMP for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, lamp, phusion-passenger

I'm working on setting up my first server on Linode.

I have:

- installed apache
- installed mysql
- installed passenger
- installed php
- bunch of other things

I'm pretty sure my Passenger + rails is mostly working (have an error, but that's a different question, and at least passenger lets me know I have an error).

My issue is that non of the php is being run for the blog. Chrome just downloads the file.

Php is installed:

```
# php -v
PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3ppa1~lucid1 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan 15 2011 23:52:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
with Suhosin v0.9.31, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH
```

In my virtual host `/etc/apache2/sites-available/MYDOMAIN.com` I have:

```
<VirtualHost 173.255.244.242:80>
    ServerAdmin ryan@MYDOMAIN.com
    ServerName MYDOMAIN.com
    ServerAlias www.MYDOMAIN.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/MYDOMAIN.com/application/public
    ErrorLog /srv/www/MYDOMAIN.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /srv/www/MYDOMAIN.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 173.255.244.242:80>
    ServerAdmin ryan@MYDOMAIN.com
    ServerName blog.MYDOMAIN.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/blog.MYDOMAIN.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /srv/www/blog.MYDOMAIN.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /srv/www/blog.MYDOMAIN.com/logs/access.log combined
    <Directory /srv/www/blog.MYDOMAIN.com/public_html>
            PassengerEnabled off
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I thought this would turn off passenger on my blog and let PHP do its thing, but it doesn't seem to work that way. I know that is is pointing in the right spot because if I put a html file there it works and it downloads the php files. Any suggestions?

I'm running on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just needed:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin ryan@MYDOMAIN.com
  ServerName blog.MYDOMAIN.com
  DocumentRoot /srv/www/blog.MYDOMAIN.com/public_html
  ErrorLog /srv/www/blog.MYDOMAIN.com/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /srv/www/blog.MYDOMAIN.com/logs/access.log combined
    <Directory /srv/www/blog.MYDOMAIN.com/public_html>
       PassengerEnabled off
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
       AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```